# MySQL function reaches a limit in time difference calculation

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've created a function for mysql using phpmyadmin (that works fine). It calculates de diference between two dates in days, hours, minutes and seconds. The output could be one like this:

5d 16h 24m 56s

The mentioned function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_full(A DATETIME, B DATETIME) RETURNS  VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN

RETURN CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(A,B))/24),'d '
               ,MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(A,B)),24), 'h '
               ,MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(A,B)),'m '
               ,SECOND(TIMEDIFF(A, B)),'s');

END
```

So after creating it and checking that works fine I decided to make it calculate a big gap of time between two dates, something like 2 months or so, but the biggest gap that it can calculates is:

34d 22h 59m 59s

**Anyone knows why? (That's the big question)**

I knew something was happening since with the query function:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created, sol_provided)) AS timeDiff
```

I was having a trouble since the biggest gap in hours that it could calculate was something like 848 hours or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL website (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

`The result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for TIME values`

Then if you continue to the section on TIME, (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html)

`TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).`

Comment: Since you were faster searching for it I'll give you the correct answer even if I explained down there more accurately. Thanks for your time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer. It turns out that TIMEDIFF(a,b) returns a TIME type value (doesn't apper in documentation but if you execute it you can see it).

> TIMEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and
>   expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the
>   same type.

And about the limitation I discovered that:

> TIME values may range from ‘-838:59:59′ to ‘838:59:59′.

So in case we want to calculate a gap greater than 838 hours we need s olution, which could be the following one:

```
# Number of days * 24 + time difference.

SELECT
DATEDIFF('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2009-01-01 00:00:00') * 24
+ EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '2010-01-01 00:00:00')
- EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '2009-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Another solution to my first function would be the following one which overtakes the limitation easily:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION time_full(A DATETIME, B DATETIME) RETURNS VARCHAR(30)

BEGIN 
    RETURN CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,A,B),'d ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,A,B), 24),'h ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,A,B), 60),'m '
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,A,B), 60),'s ');
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think `time_full` would be better to return a BIGINT rather than a VARCHAR... I'll leave that as an exercise for the next commenter to implement :D